# Combo box guess and search from user input?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have a combobox with more than 10000 elements. I'm looking for a way when user open combobox and type for instance 'a' it brings all the element start with 'a' and when user type 'ai' it brings up all the elements start with 'ai' I don't know what they call it but please let me know if there is pre-written library or example?

Comment: If you don't mind using a 3rd party library, take a look SwingX's autocomplete support or [this](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/) or [this](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can take a look to [swingx](http://swingx.java.net/) that have JComboBox with autocomplete feature, specially `AutoCompleteDecorator`

Example:

```
this.comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi",
        "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.comboBox);
```